# I may be thought dishonest - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I may be thought dishonest
But I’m often spoken over
And you may not understand the words

By another name, I would place my weight on you
Or at least allude to your work.

You must pick me
Or later, give me a bow

**Hint 1**

> While "you may not understand the words," they may still be music to your ears.

Comment: Are we allowed to know the meaning of "bow"? A weapon? Gesture? Tie alternative?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev, figuring that out is kinda part of the riddle, but I'll add a hint tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> a **lyre** ?

I may be thought dishonest

> sounds like "liar"

But I’m often spoken over
And you may not understand the words

> The recitations of the Ancient Greeks were accompanied by lyre playing. And I wouldn't understand those words, because "they're Greek to me"...

By another name, I would place my weight on you

> Lyres are defined as "yoke lutes".

Or at least allude to your work.

> The term is also used metaphorically to refer to the work or skill of a poet.

You must pick me
Or later, give me a bow

> The lyre of classical antiquity was ordinarily played by being strummed with a plectrum (pick).  However, later lyres were played with a bow.

(Citing Wikipedia for most of my explanations)

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyre

Comment: I was going to say that, but couldn't come up with the work either...

Comment: Hmmm... well there you have it.

Comment: This is it! You nailed it.

Comment: My complete list after lyre was bow/beau, phony/ey... but for various reasons didn't quite fit. I even also entertained 'trumped' for a while. And 'rap'/wrap made an appearance for a while, lol. Good job.

Comment: @kayzeroshort, the larger lyres were played resting on the body. That may reference the weight as well.

Comment: ah, that's clever!

Answer (score 6):

Are you :

> A violin (/fiddle?)

I may be thought dishonest

> Dishonest: “He's always on the fiddle.”

But I’m often spoken over

> Violins often play in orchestras with other instruments playing over it

And you may not understand the words

> Words of music

By another name, I would place my weight on you

> Not sure about the "By another name" part, but you place the weight of a violin on your shoulder.

Or at least allude to your work.

> Not sure about this one. maybe works as in a piece from a composer?

You must pick me

> Not sure either. is "picking" maybe a technique on a violin? Like plucking?

Or later, give me a bow

> A bow is used to play the violin

Comment: Quite a few clues are missing answers here...

Comment: This was my immediate thought.

Answer (score 5):

Are you :

> Plagiarism?

I may be thought dishonest

> Plagiarism constitutes an act of academic dishonesty

But I’m often spoken over

> Lots of people already used that before, and it is still being used

And you may not understand the words

> Plagiarizing is sometimes done in hast, thus leading to the plagiarist not understanding all of the work he is plagiarizing

By another name, I would place my weight on you

> You can give another name to the original author's one to refer to his work

Or at least allude to your work.

> You can include a citation, thus giving credit to the original author, even if a citation might not be enough.

You must pick me

> Can't find something for this line...

Or later, give me a bow

> If the plagiarism comes successful, then you have to thank it (that basically comes down to thank yourself).

Comment: Creative answer, but not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Are you :

> Sight / looking

I may be thought dishonest

> Looks can be deceiving

But I’m often spoken over

> Oversight / overlook

And you may not understand the words

> A picture is worth a thousand words

By another name, I would place my weight on you

> Not sure about this

Or at least allude to your work.

> You can 'cite' another work

Not sure about the rest.

Comment: I like this one, but it's not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> Dubbed?

I may be thought dishonest

> A dubbed TV show may have messages changed or lost in translation, or it may have entire scenes dropped due to laws or cultural differences

But I’m often spoken over

> A dubbed track is 'spoken over' the original footage

And you may not understand the words

> Well I've all been there, accidentally watching a dubbed version of something in a language we don't understand.

By another name, I would place my weight on you

> You could be dubbed with a title hat carries weight?

Or at least allude to your work.

> Or just one that implies what you do for a living eg. Dr.

You must pick me

> Dubbed can mean chosen

Or later, give me a bow

> Bowing as you are struck lightly with a sword to become a knight?

Comment: No, sorry this isn't the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Disclaimer?

I May be thought dishonest

> Some people think disclaimers hide information

But I am often spoken over

> in commercials disclaimer are read rapidly underneath actor portrayals

And you might not understand the words

> because they are read so rapidly it can be hard to catch all of a disclaimer

By another name, I place my weight on you

> A disclaimer is about responsibility, which can be a "weight on your shoulders"

Or at least allude to your work

> What you claim responsibility for alludes to what you intended your product for

You must pick me

> almost everything needs a disclaimer to protect the creators from lawsuits

Or later, give me a bow

> if you don't do a disclaimer a lawsuit could bankrupt you forcing you to "bow" to the debt.

Comment: Disclaimer: this is not correct. :P

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> musical trill?

I may be thought dishonest
But I’m often spoken over
And you may not understand the words

> Dishonest, because in musical notation a trill may be written as a single note even though there are multiple notes being played. This can be indicated by a bar or letters written over it ("spoken over") to indicate the trill should happen.

By another name, I would place my weight on you
Or at least allude to your work.

> Not sure. "Quaver" is a synonym for trill, and maybe that sounds like learning on someone else? Not confident about that.

You must pick me
Or later, give me a bow

> On a violin it's easiest to play the trill by picking the two strings, but maybe a more talented violinist can perform the trill with the bow as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Toddler?

I may be thought dishonest

> Toddlers are prown to stretching the truth.

But I’m often spoken over

> Adults will often converse while toddlers attempt to get their attention.

And you may not understand the words

> Toddlers may say unintelligible things since they are new to whatever language they speak.

By another name, I would place my weight on you

> A person may allude to their toddler as their child who is often carried thus putting their weight on an adult.

Or at least allude to your work.

> Referring to a todddler as your child alludes to your "work" put in to make them exist.

You must pick me

> This could refer to picking them up as mentioned before.

Or later, give me a bow

> If you don't pick them up initially, later you must bow down to pick them up when they no longer want to walk.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> word of praise

I may be thought dishonest
But I’m often spoken over

> a praise may be considered flattery, and ignored

And you may not understand the words

> It may be indirect

By another name, I would place my weight on you

> another word for praise is merit, so it may sound like a responsibilty

Or at least allude to your work.

> another synonym is commendation, which is also similar to a citation

You must pick me
Or later, give me a bow

> accept praise gracefully?